# HighChart not showing anything

Tags: highcharts

Can anyone maybe tell me what I am doing wrong here. Because my Chart shows the X values but my Y values does not plot on the chart.

Note reason for this x: and y: is because I am using dotnet highchart helper.

```
chart: {    renderTo:'chart_0_container', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', className: 'chart1', defaultSeriesType: 'line', marginRight: 10, plotShadow: false, resetZoomButton: { position: { align: 'left' } }, zoomType: 'xy' }, 
    xAxis: { allowDecimals: false, type: 'linear' },
    yAxis: [{ labels: { formatter: function () {return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,2,'.' ,' ');} }, max: 0, title: { text: '' } }], 
    legend: { enabled: true },
    tooltip: { enabled: true, formatter: function() { return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + ';">●</span> ' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,',','.') + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat(' %Y-%m-%d %H:%M (%A)' , new Date(this.x)); } },  
    title: { text: '' },  
    plotOptions: { line: { marker: { enabled: true } } }, 
    exporting: { enabled: true, filename: 'TrendExport' }, 
    series: [{ data: 
        [{ x: 49.898418, y: 21.32 }, 
        { x: 49.882478, y: 21.32 }, 
        { x: 51.759454, y: 21.57 }, 
        { x: 51.385514, y: 21.56 }, 
        { x: 50.678916, y: 21.47 }, 
        { x: 50.226594, y: 21.35 }, 
        { x: 49.956602, y: 21.25 }, 
        { x: 49.841858, y: 21.24 }, 
        { x: 49.865894, y: 21.28 }, 
        { x: 49.845258, y: 21.31 }, 
        { x: 49.797864, y: 21.21 }, 
        { x: 49.880792, y: 21.29 }, 
        { x: 50.863658, y: 21.31 }, 
        { x: 50.017988, y: 21.21 }, 
        { x: 49.98614, y: 21.21 }, 
        { x: 50.105496, y: 21.29 }, 
        { x: 49.712604, y: 21.19 }, 
        { x: 49.714074, y: 21.2 }, 
        { x: 49.756014, y: 21.19 }, 
        { x: 49.817874, y: 21.23 }, 
        { x: 49.798772, y: 21.21 }, 
        { x: 50.006356, y: 21.3 }, 
        { x: 50.06892, y: 21.32 }, 
        { x: 49.77289, y: 21.21 }, 
        { x: 49.700852, y: 21.2 }, 
        { x: 49.653704, y: 21.19 }, 
        { x: 49.736278, y: 21.21 }, 
        { x: 49.757966, y: 21.21 }, 
        { x: 49.7942, y: 21.22 }, 
        { x: 49.75787, y: 21.21 }], name: 'ABSA Capital Durban Incomer (kVAr)' }]
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Your data is not sorted , Highcharts expects data to be sorted  http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should get sorted data from back-end logic and provide that to your chart .If it can't be in sorted order do following :
Put your series data in a variable and sort the data using:

```
   var dataToSort = [{ x: 49.898418, y: 21.32 }, 
                     { x: 49.882478, y: 21.32 }, 
                     { x: 51.759454, y: 21.57 }, 
                     { x: 51.385514, y: 21.56 }, 
                     { x: 50.678916, y: 21.47 }, 
                     { x: 50.226594, y: 21.35 }, 
                      //  .......and so on

   dataToSort.sort(function(a, b) {
   return parseFloat(a.x) - parseFloat(b.x);
   });
```

Also remove the date-formatter in tooltip, Itsdoesn't seem that your data has any timestamp or UTC date in x field .

Also as mentioned by @mekhatria remove max:0

See [Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/7nvk3uv9/1/)

Comment: Thank you greatly for your exprienced help.

Comment: @mekhatria, Same to you it really helpe me alot.

Answer (score 1):

You have max:0 in yAxis.
Fix it here :), check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/njby5630/)

```
yAxis: [{
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 2, '.', ' ');
    }
  },
  //max: 0,
  title: {
    text: ''
  }
}],
legend: {
  enabled: true
},
```